# Drawing overlay with circle(radius) on MapView

Tags: android, android-maps

I want to draw a circle on MapView, i.e. radius. I do it like this:

**Overlay to draw circle:**

```
public class RadiusOverlay extends Overlay {

    private Context context;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private float radius;

    public RadiusOverlay(Context context, double latitude, double longitude, float radius){
     /*.....................*/
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); 

        Point point = new Point();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude *1e6), (int)(longitude * 1e6));

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
        radius = projection.metersToEquatorPixels(radius);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setARGB(100, 100, 100, 100);

        canvas.drawCircle((float)point.x, (float)point.y, radius, paint);
    }

}
```

**In MapActivity:**

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
RadiusOverlay radiusOverlay = new RadiusOverlay(this, latitude, longitude, radius);
mapOverlays.add(radiusOverlay);
```

I see circle when MapActivity starts, and it's the size I intended, but then it grows to the size of the screen and disappears. How do I fix this?
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: When it starts to grow? When you change you zoom level or may be move a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are re-calculating the radius using `metersToEquatorPixels` every time you draw it. You should move that calculation to the constructor and see if that fixes your problem.

EDIT:

As Olgas pointed out, the Projection can change. Therefore what you want to do is store the original `radius value as you are, then in your draw method do:

```
    float projectedRadius = projection.metersToEquatorPixels(radius);
```

and use this value later in draw as well:

```
    canvas.drawCircle((float)point.x, (float)point.y, projectedRadius, paint);
```

Comment: I think it is wrong. The javadoc for getProjection method says "You should not hold on to this object for more than one draw, since the projection of the map could change."

Comment: I was keeping recalculating radius based on previous radius value, i.e. I took radius in pixels(from previous onDraw() call) and tried to calculate new radius in pixels. Thanks for pointing me.

Comment: Good point. I am editing my response to reflect that point Olegas